# Jquery Mansory div overlapping

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

I'm using jquery [masonry plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/) for the layout shown in this [image](http://oi41.tinypic.com/33k51n7.jpg). The problem is the masonry plugin hides the div that are shaded in the black color as shown in this [image](http://oi42.tinypic.com/2ighg0w.jpg). Is there is any solution to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Masonry takes all the white boxes and gives them position absolute inside a container, the container in this case has the black boxes and white boxes together (am i right?) something like this:

```
   <div id="container">
      <div class="black-box"></div>
      <div class="black-box"></div>
      <div class="white-box"></div>
      <div class="white-box"></div>
      <div class="white-box"></div>
      <div class="white-box"></div>
   </div>
```

In order to fix this, you need to put all the white boxes in their own container and give it position:relative, and then do the masonry on the white-boxes container

```
<div id="container">
      <div class="black-box"></div>
      <div class="black-box"></div>
      <div id="white-boxes-container">
         <div class="white-box"></div>
         <div class="white-box"></div>
         <div class="white-box"></div>
         <div class="white-box"></div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: No, I am already placing that black-box div outside of the container. Still it overlaps the black box. And if I give float-left to the container id it sits next to the black box but the masonry plugin not works.

Comment: does the white-boxes container have position:relative?

Comment: Is is possible to take a look at your code? using jsFiddle or something

Comment: Because the container is being resized dynamically, safest thing to do is not to rely on the natural floating behaviour of elements: http://jsfiddle.net/wa8CW/2/

Comment: Solved! just add overflow:hidden to container div.